# Falsche Verwendung des Genus: negativer Eindruck?

Tags: grammatical-case, article

Ich lerne Deutsch seit 2011, aber ich habe nicht alle Artikel gelernt. Die Leute sagen, dass mein Deutsch "sehr gut ist", aber es ist ziemlich klar, dass ich nicht so gut darin bin.

Ich glaube, dass falsche Artikelverwendung es deutlich macht. Würdet Ihr sagen, dass falsche Artikelwahl bzw. Deklination der Adjektiven einen schlechten Eindruck erweckt?

Comment: Was meinst du mit "nicht alle Artikeln gelernt"? Falsche Verwendung des Genus?

Comment: @c.p. Genau. Tut mir leid.

Comment: @c.p. Studierst du Physik?

Comment: Related question in English: [How do Germans react to foreigners messing up noun genders?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/13548/9551)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeder deutsche Muttersprachler WEISS, wie schwer die Artikel für einen Nicht- Muttersprachler sind. Insofern ist die Verwendung des falschen Artikels in keinster Weise mit einem schlechten / negativen Eindruck belegt.

Es gibt sicher Situationen, in denen eine einwandfreie Deklination und Artikelwahl unabdingbar ist (z.B. wenn Du Dich als Journalist oder auch Werbefachmann bewirbst), in den meisten Situationen im täglichen Leben wird darauf eher wenig Wert gelegt.

Comment: Widerspruch: **Nicht** jeder Muttersprachler weiß, wie schwer die Artikel für einen Nicht-Muttersprachler sind. In meiner Kindheit und Jugend war mir das keineswegs bewusst, weil Artikel bzw. Geschlechter so etwas grundlegendes sind, dass man daran gar keinen Gedanken verschwendet. Und wenn man zum ersten Mal auf jemanden trifft, der »der Sonne« und »die Mond« sagt, ist das sehr irritierend. Wenn man mehr mit Leuten zu tun hat, die schlecht Deutsch sprechen, wird man das gewohnt, aber zumindest ich finde es nach wie vor störend.

Answer (score 0):

Es ist nicht schlimmer als englischsprechende Deutsche, die konsequent die englischen Zeitformen durcheinanderbringen. Denn: da ist das Deutsche ja wunderbar entspannt.